# Как сделать "ручку" в NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, sliding, control-panel

Дорый день!
В общем, нужно сделать меню навигации, но с ручкой, за которую пользователь вытягивает саму менюшку. Пробовал SlidingDrawer, но там пишет "Deprecated". Заходил также в Android Arsenal, переберал все Sliding Panels, но нет ни одной, которая мне нужна, помогите пожалуйста, а то запыхался искать! Нечто похожее есть например в Google калькуляторе, синяя панелька с ручкой, ты её вытягваешь и там кнопочки всякие.[image: Пример того, что я хочу[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3NYK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно добавить `BottomSheet`. Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка этого элемента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bottom_sheet_peek"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bottom_sheet_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

и вот как оно реализовано в активности:

```
// get the bottom sheet view
LinearLayout llBottomSheet = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

// init the bottom sheet behavior
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(llBottomSheet);

// change the state of the bottom sheet
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

// set the peek height
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(340);

// set hideable or not
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);

// set callback for changes
bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

    }
});
```

Вот [тут](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066) размещен первоисточник. [Тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/) перевод и доп информация. [Вот](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets) документация и [библиотека](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) которая реализует требуемый функционал.

Comment: BottomSheet мне не нужен, вместо него я сделал SlidingUpPanel, по другие задачи, мне нужна именно БОКОВАЯ панелька с ручкой, как меню навигации, но с ручкой!

Comment: так там можно вбок свайп сделать и все))

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, пойду попробую, и т.е. оно будет выглядеть как я хочу, тип ручка и шторка?) (Извините за тупые вопросы, я просто новичок) :)

Comment: Никакой ручки не будет, просто свайп от левого края экрана и ваше меню выезжает)))

Comment: А всё-таки, если хочу чтобы была ручка, как это можно реализовать? (Для удобства пользователя)

Comment: я бы не советовал использовать ручку, так как это будет конфликтовать с свайпом самой вьюхи меню. Но если все-таки вы хотите сделать ручку - берете обычную вьюшку, любую (view например) делаете нужную вам форму, делаете фон и крепите возле левого края экрана, там где вам нужно, прописываете действия на свайп и отключаете свайп у самого меню, но мне кажется что идея не очень если честно

Comment: можете подробнее объяснить пожалуйста как это делается??? (Буду очень благодарен :D )